# How to connect mobile broadband using terminal?

Tags: command-line, connection, mobile-broadband

I configured new-mobile-broadband connection. I know that I can connect by clicking as following:

[image: screen-shot]

But I want to connect manually to that mobile broadband **by using terminal**.

How to do with terminal command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect using the command :

```
nmcli con up id '<BROADBAND CONNECTION NAME HERE>'
```

Ex:

```
nmcli con up id 'BSNL/CellOne New GPRS/3G'
```

For better output, use the following command :

```
sleep 10 && nmcli nm wwan on && nmcli con up id 'BSNL/CellOne New GPRS/3G'
```

Comment: Could you please explain the command? That would be immensely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain please ? I have tested with `nmcli tool, version 1.14.6` and I have `Error: argument 'nm' not understood. Try passing --help instead.` I dont know how to get the ID.